# AutomationElement shows up using Inspect.exe but does show not up when using UIAutomationCore.dll or System.Windows.Automation

Tags: c#, .net, automation, ui-automation

**TL;DR**: What am I doing wrong that is causing the workspace pane to show up in Inspect Objects but not show up in my custom code?

---

I am trying to write some UI automation to a 3rd party program. I am using [Inspect.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that came with the [Windows SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8279), and I have tried both [System.Windows.Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590934.aspx) and direct [COM Calls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms726294%28VS.85%29.aspx) (using the wrapper library from [UIA Verify](http://uiautomationverify.codeplex.com/)).

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("Redacted Client");
if (processes.Length == 0) throw new Exception("Could not find \"Redacted Client\" process");

PropertyCondition parentFileCond = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ProcessIdProperty, processes[0].Id);
PropertyCondition workspaceCond = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Workspace", PropertyConditionFlags.IgnoreCase);
PropertyCondition documentCond = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Untitled3", PropertyConditionFlags.IgnoreCase);

var parentElement = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, parentFileCond);
var workspaceElement = parentElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, workspaceCond); //Also does not work with TreeScope.Descendants
var documentElement = workspaceElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, documentCond);
```

When I try the above code, `parentElement` does have the correct reference to the main program window, but `workspaceElement` is null.

---

### A temporary workaround:

If I change my `documentElement` code to:

```
var documentElement = parentElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, documentCond);
```

I will get the correct element returned. I can use this as a workaround as the document window is the one I really wanted anyway, but I would like to know why the Workspace pane would not show up so I can improve my skills in case I run into this in the future with a situation I cannot work around.

---

UPDATE: I tried MrGomez's suggestions

```
PropertyCondition parentFileCond = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ProcessIdProperty, 5872);
PropertyCondition panelCond = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Pane);

var parentElement = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, parentFileCond);
var panels = parentElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, panelCond);
```

[image]

I get 3 results, unfortunately, I have 4 panels, and the one that did not show up was the panel named `Workspace`.

I also tried to use a [TreeWalker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.treewalker.treewalker.aspx)

```
PropertyCondition parentFileCond = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ProcessIdProperty, 5872);
PropertyCondition workspaceCond= new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Workspace");

var walker = new TreeWalker(workspaceCond);
var parentElement = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, parentFileCond);
var workspaceElement = walker.Normalize(parentElement);
```

but that also returns null for `workspaceElement`

Finally, in desperation, I tried the current value of "NativeWindowHandle" from Inspect and started the walking from the root node.

```
PropertyCondition workspaceCond = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NativeWindowHandleProperty, 0x110906);
var walker = new TreeWalker(workspaceCond);
var workspaceElement = walker.Normalize(AutomationElement.RootElement);
```

Workspace element is *STILL* null.

---

### Result Found

I finally did get Workspace to show up, but I had to perform

```
PropertyCondition workspaceCond = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NativeWindowHandleProperty, 0x110906);
var test = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Subtree, workspaceCond);
```

and it took quite a while to run.

### Old Screen Captures

Here is screenshots from Inspect.exe showing the tree view.

[image]

Here are the properties of the main window of the program.

```
How found:  Selected from tree...
RuntimeId:  "[42.2557552]"
BoundingRectangle:  {l:75 t:1 r:1311 b:1003}
ProcessId:  8160
ControlType:    UIA_WindowControlTypeId (0xC370)
LocalizedControlType:   "window"
Name:   "Redacted"
AccessKey:  ""
HasKeyboardFocus:   false
IsKeyboardFocusable:    true
IsEnabled:  true
ClassName:  "C:\Program Files (x86)\RedactedProgramFiles7\RedactedClientFolder"
HelpText:   ""
IsPassword: false
NativeWindowHandle: 0x270670
IsOffscreen:    false
FrameworkId:    "Win32"
ProviderDescription:    "[pid:4000,hwnd:0x270670 Main:Nested [pid:8160,hwnd:0x270670 Annotation(parent link):Microsoft: Annotation Proxy (unmanaged:uiautomationcore.dll); Main:Microsoft: MSAA Proxy (unmanaged:uiautomationcore.dll)]; Nonclient:Microsoft: Non-Client Proxy (unmanaged:uiautomationcore.dll); Hwnd(parent link):Microsoft: HWND Proxy (unmanaged:uiautomationcore.dll)]"
Window.CanMaximize: true
Window.CanMinimize: true
Window.WindowVisualState:   Normal (0)
Window.WindowInteractionState:  ReadyForUserInteraction (2)
Window.IsModal: false
Window.IsTopmost:   false
Transform.CanMove:  true
Transform.CanResize:    true
Transform.CanRotate:    false
LegacyIAccessible.ChildId:  0
LegacyIAccessible.DefaultAction:    ""
LegacyIAccessible.Description:  ""
LegacyIAccessible.Help: ""
LegacyIAccessible.KeyboardShortcut: ""
LegacyIAccessible.Name: "Redacted"
LegacyIAccessible.Role: client (0xA)
LegacyIAccessible.State:    focusable (0x100000)
LegacyIAccessible.Value:    ""
IsDockPatternAvailable: false
IsExpandCollapsePatternAvailable:   false
IsGridItemPatternAvailable: false
IsGridPatternAvailable: false
IsInvokePatternAvailable:   false
IsLegacyIAccessiblePatternAvailable:    true
IsMultipleViewPatternAvailable: false
IsRangeValuePatternAvailable:   false
IsScrollPatternAvailable:   false
IsScrollItemPatternAvailable:   false
IsSelectionItemPatternAvailable:    false
IsSelectionPatternAvailable:    false
IsTablePatternAvailable:    false
IsTableItemPatternAvailable:    false
IsTextPatternAvailable: false
IsTogglePatternAvailable:   false
IsTransformPatternAvailable:    true
IsValuePatternAvailable:    false
IsWindowPatternAvailable:   true
IsItemContainerPatternAvailable:    false
IsVirtualizedItemPatternAvailable:  false
IsSynchronizedInputPatternAvailable:    false
FirstChild: "Workspace" pane
LastChild:  "Application" menu bar
Next:   "Inspect  (HWND: 0x01700F06)" window
Previous:   "Sandbox Console (Debugging) - Microsoft Visual Studio (Administrator)" window
Other Props:    Object has no additional properties
Children:   "Workspace" pane
    (null) title bar
    "Application" menu bar
Ancestors:  "Desktop" pane
    [ No Parent ]
```

Here are the properties of the problem "Workspace" pane.

```
How found:  Selected from tree...
RuntimeId:  "[42.34146524]"
BoundingRectangle:  {l:83 t:51 r:1303 b:995}
ProcessId:  8160
ControlType:    UIA_PaneControlTypeId (0xC371)
LocalizedControlType:   "pane"
Name:   "Workspace"
AccessKey:  ""
HasKeyboardFocus:   false
IsKeyboardFocusable:    true
IsEnabled:  true
ClassName:  "MDIClient"
HelpText:   ""
IsPassword: false
NativeWindowHandle: 0x20908DC
IsOffscreen:    false
FrameworkId:    "Win32"
ProviderDescription:    "[pid:4000,hwnd:0x20908DC Main:Nested [pid:8160,hwnd:0x20908DC Annotation(parent link):Microsoft: Annotation Proxy (unmanaged:uiautomationcore.dll); Main:Microsoft: MSAA Proxy (unmanaged:uiautomationcore.dll)]; Hwnd(parent link):Microsoft: HWND Proxy (unmanaged:uiautomationcore.dll)]"
LegacyIAccessible.ChildId:  0
LegacyIAccessible.DefaultAction:    ""
LegacyIAccessible.Description:  ""
LegacyIAccessible.Help: ""
LegacyIAccessible.KeyboardShortcut: ""
LegacyIAccessible.Name: "Workspace"
LegacyIAccessible.Role: client (0xA)
LegacyIAccessible.State:    focusable (0x100000)
LegacyIAccessible.Value:    ""
IsDockPatternAvailable: false
IsExpandCollapsePatternAvailable:   false
IsGridItemPatternAvailable: false
IsGridPatternAvailable: false
IsInvokePatternAvailable:   false
IsLegacyIAccessiblePatternAvailable:    true
IsMultipleViewPatternAvailable: false
IsRangeValuePatternAvailable:   false
IsScrollPatternAvailable:   false
IsScrollItemPatternAvailable:   false
IsSelectionItemPatternAvailable:    false
IsSelectionPatternAvailable:    false
IsTablePatternAvailable:    false
IsTableItemPatternAvailable:    false
IsTextPatternAvailable: false
IsTogglePatternAvailable:   false
IsTransformPatternAvailable:    false
IsValuePatternAvailable:    false
IsWindowPatternAvailable:   false
IsItemContainerPatternAvailable:    false
IsVirtualizedItemPatternAvailable:  false
IsSynchronizedInputPatternAvailable:    false
FirstChild: "Untitled3" window
LastChild:  "Letters (32638 of 32638):" window
Next:   (null) title bar
Previous:   [null]
Other Props:    Object has no additional properties
Children:   "Untitled3" window
    "Letters (32638 of 32638):" window
Ancestors:  "Redacted" window
    "Desktop" pane
    [ No Parent ]
```

Here are the properties of the "Working" document window.

```
How found:  Selected from tree...
RuntimeId:  "[42.9505096]"
BoundingRectangle:  {l:85 t:53 r:651 b:491}
ProcessId:  8160
ControlType:    UIA_WindowControlTypeId (0xC370)
LocalizedControlType:   "window"
Name:   "Untitled3"
AccessKey:  ""
HasKeyboardFocus:   false
IsKeyboardFocusable:    true
IsEnabled:  true
AutomationId:   "10"
ClassName:  "ProToolsSubMDIWndClass"
HelpText:   ""
IsPassword: false
NativeWindowHandle: 0x910948
IsOffscreen:    false
FrameworkId:    "Win32"
ProviderDescription:    "[pid:4000,hwnd:0x910948 Main:Nested [pid:8160,hwnd:0x910948 Annotation(parent link):Microsoft: Annotation Proxy (unmanaged:uiautomationcore.dll); Main:Microsoft: MSAA Proxy (unmanaged:uiautomationcore.dll)]; Nonclient:Microsoft: Non-Client Proxy (unmanaged:uiautomationcore.dll); Hwnd(parent link):Microsoft: HWND Proxy (unmanaged:uiautomationcore.dll)]"
Window.CanMaximize: true
Window.CanMinimize: true
Window.WindowVisualState:   Normal (0)
Window.WindowInteractionState:  ReadyForUserInteraction (2)
Window.IsModal: false
Window.IsTopmost:   false
Transform.CanMove:  true
Transform.CanResize:    true
Transform.CanRotate:    false
LegacyIAccessible.ChildId:  0
LegacyIAccessible.DefaultAction:    ""
LegacyIAccessible.Description:  ""
LegacyIAccessible.Help: ""
LegacyIAccessible.KeyboardShortcut: ""
LegacyIAccessible.Name: "Untitled3"
LegacyIAccessible.Role: client (0xA)
LegacyIAccessible.State:    focusable (0x100000)
LegacyIAccessible.Value:    ""
IsDockPatternAvailable: false
IsExpandCollapsePatternAvailable:   false
IsGridItemPatternAvailable: false
IsGridPatternAvailable: false
IsInvokePatternAvailable:   false
IsLegacyIAccessiblePatternAvailable:    true
IsMultipleViewPatternAvailable: false
IsRangeValuePatternAvailable:   false
IsScrollPatternAvailable:   false
IsScrollItemPatternAvailable:   false
IsSelectionItemPatternAvailable:    false
IsSelectionPatternAvailable:    false
IsTablePatternAvailable:    false
IsTableItemPatternAvailable:    false
IsTextPatternAvailable: false
IsTogglePatternAvailable:   false
IsTransformPatternAvailable:    true
IsValuePatternAvailable:    false
IsWindowPatternAvailable:   true
IsItemContainerPatternAvailable:    false
IsVirtualizedItemPatternAvailable:  false
IsSynchronizedInputPatternAvailable:    false
FirstChild: "" thumb
LastChild:  (null) title bar
Next:   "Letters (32638 of 32638):" window
Previous:   [null]
Other Props:    Object has no additional properties
Children:   "" thumb
    (null) title bar
Ancestors:  "Workspace" pane
    "Redacted" window
    "Desktop" pane
    [ No Parent ]
```

Comment: Nit: I assume you meant `TreeScope.Descendants` in your comment above?

Comment: Do me a favor, since you have this code in your IDE? Do a quick [`autoElement.GetCurrentPropertyValue(AutomationElement.NameProperty, true)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement.nameproperty.aspx) on your Workspace pane and see what it comes up with. If this returns "Workspace" correctly, something else is clearly wrong.

Comment: We can further refine this by seeing if `PropertyCondition workspaceCond = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Pane);` returns non-null when evaluated against your tree. If this corrects the traversal, then the trick will be to figure out why your name property isn't evaluating properly. From a cursory documentation walk, your code _should_ just work, but it clearly isn't.

Comment: It will be a few as I have a long running process running in the software (one of the things I was trying to automate was so I don't need to baby sit error dialogs that must be dismissed for the program to continue during this operation that can pop up randomly). Once it is done I will update my question.

Comment: No problem. Your first-name doppleganger [asked a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711119/how-do-i-bring-set-focus-of-mdi-child-window-using-uiautomation) that implies your conditional should be evaluating correctly. So, two thoughts come to mind: (1) your "Workspace" name isn't in place at traversal time or (2) a potential bug is extant in the current code, preventing the expression from evaluating successfully. I'd advise, just for debugging, that you use a name other than "Workspace" and try `PropertyConditionFlags.None` to see if it just works.

Comment: @MrGomez I got a chance to test it, `ropertyCondition workspaceCond = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Pane);` returned null, also your `TreeWalker` suggestion in your answer also did not work (but it let me get rid of my LINQ queries for other parts that where working, thanks for that). I did get it to show up by searching **all** nodes under the root node but that will not work for practical use. See my updated question for details.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I have a similar problem and it looks like it might be related to when a MDI child form creates a non-MDI form - then that won't appear on the automation tree.  Could that have been your problem too?

Comment: @RickL Not really, I just ended up using the "search all nodes" approach, it was slow but it was better than not working at all.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Very nice question. Based upon the problem you've documented, it's clear that your conditional:

```
PropertyCondition workspaceCond = new PropertyCondition(
 AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Workspace", PropertyConditionFlags.IgnoreCase);
```

... fails evaluation. Why?

The answer is how your conditional is evaluated. Looking at your element tree, we notice this property for `Workspace`:

```
IsWindowPatternAvailable:   false
```

And for the main window and `Untitled3`:

```
IsWindowPatternAvailable:   true
```

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671199%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> ```
> UIA_IsWindowPatternAvailablePropertyId 30044
> ```
>
> Identifies the `IsWindowPatternAvailable` property, which indicates whether the Window control pattern is available for the automation element. If `TRUE`, a client can retrieve an [`IUIAutomationWindowPattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671492%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface from the element.

We find a repro [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328698/how-can-i-tell-if-an-element-matches-a-propertycondition-in-microsoft-ui-automat), which implies the same failure pattern as the one you are currently experiencing. We also note the lack of `Window` properties present for this element because `IUIAutomationWindowPattern` is inaccessible.

A workaround is available from the [aforelinked thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328698/how-can-i-tell-if-an-element-matches-a-propertycondition-in-microsoft-ui-automat). Instead of `PropertyCondition`, one might use:

```
public class ConditionMatcher : IMatchConditions
{
    public bool Matches(AutomationElement element, Condition condition)
    {
        return new TreeWalker(condition).Normalize(element) != null;
    }
}
```

Or, alternately, one might use the workaround you've given, provided your tree structure is guaranteed to be shallow (and thus, appropriate to the name of this site, will not trigger a stack overflow).

Admittedly, this wasn't the most obvious issue. In the perfect world, MSDN *should* have better documentation on this topic.

Comment: Wow thanks! it still is doing that the export from earlier (it will be several hours before it completes) but I will give this a test once I can re-create the situation and test it out.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain No problem! It's still unclear if the traversal is being _outright blocked_ by the inaccessibility of `IUIAutomationWindowPattern`, but it's the most plausible regression. Should this fail to be the case, I believe we have more than enough test cases to poke this with until we find the root cause.

Comment: The `TreeWalker` did not work either. I did get it to show up if I search all nodes under the root node and look for the window handle. but that will not work for Live use.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain _Nice_. Your repro tells us why the conditional is failing -- it can't query the name property exactly as we'd surmised. That leads me to [this thread on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsaccessibilityandautomation/thread/e8e76f2e-1ee7-4289-8cf6-30ca8feef63c), which tells a plausible story. Note that Inspect.exe is using the _native_ UIA API, while you're using the _managed_ API. Therefore, the next test becomes the following: what does UISpy have to say about your windows? If it's missing the name property, then using the native API is the right fix.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Neat! For the benefit of others seeking out this information, please do let us know what worked for you. :)

Comment: I have not had time to work on it, been very busy with other things, but the bounty was expiring soon and you helped me a lot along the away so I gave you the credit.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Fair enough! Do let me know when and if you have additional questions. Even without rep at stake, I'm always glad to help. :)