# TreeWalker cant see AutomationElement, but UIA Verify can

Tags: ui-automation

I'm using the UI Automation Framework and I'm trying to parse my UI using a TreeWalker. 
(I have also tried the solutions suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282275/automationelement-shows-up-using-inspect-exe-but-does-show-not-up-when-using-uia) but it didn't help much.)

I have a single pane which contain one child pane and several child buttons. They're all on the same level so I suppose we could call them siblings. When I use the TreeWalker to parse the elements, I can only 'see' the pane - never the buttons - which im actually after.

What bugs me is when I use UIA Verify and select one of these buttons, it manages to build and draw the hierarchy. Then, if I select via the context menu to "Go to sibling", I can easily jump between the child pane and other child buttons.

I've tried all different versions of the TreeWalker e.g. Control and Raw, yet I end up with the same results - nothing - it only sees the child pane.

Can someone perhaps give me a high level overview of how UIA Verify is able to build up its hierarchy and still show (and manage to navigate between) all components? Why can't I replicate that in code?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same frustrations! Can find things easily in UIA Verify - no possible way to get the same node via TreeWalker that I've been able to accomplish.

Comment: You can always look at the source of [UIA Verify](http://uiautomationverify.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that you were using built-in managed UIA wrapper. Is it the case?
Managed version uses UIA v2, which has known limitations/problems. UIA Verify uses UIA v3 through COM directly.

To verify is it the case, you may try using [UISpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848721/where-do-i-get-ui-spy) instead of UIA Verify. It uses old managed wrappers as well, so if it has same problems as your code - it would be sort of confirmation.

Instead of built-in wrapper you may want to use [UIAComWrapper](https://github.com/JakeGinnivan/UIAComWrapper/), which provides the same API, but uses COM/UIA v3 under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is the problem and I don't have your application so I can test it, but did you try to use AutomationElement.FindAll function? If you want to retreive all children of an element you can use a code like this:

```
collection = parent.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition);
```

This will return control children. You can also try to test your application with this [tool](http://automationspy.freecluster.eu/) and see if it finds the buttons. This tool is made with .NET Framework 4.0. Have luck!