# Hosting Word in Browser - AutomationElement IsWindowPatternAvailable - how to set it?

Tags: c#, wpf, ui-automation, automationelement

We are hosting `MS-Word` documents in a `WebBrowser control` in a `WPF application`.

The `WebBrowser control` shows the following dialogue during the navigation to a selected MS-Word document:

[image: File Download dialogue]

We try to close the dialogue programmatically using `AutomationElement`. The code works without any problems in a test application. When we adapt the code in our real application (`edit` the file, show file with `mail merge`), only the `mail merge` part is closing the dialogue correctly. In the other case the AutomationElement for the dialogue can not be found.

We have found out that our code is failing when the AutomationElement for the dialogue has `IsWindowPatternAvailable = false`.

Is there a way to set this property in advance? Or a reason why it is true in one case and false in another?

The test application is a "standard WPF-Application"-project. It only contains the MainWindow.xaml.cs and MainWindow.xaml. 
Clicking a button sets the `Source` for the `WebBrowser`:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(backgroundCheck));
        thread.Start();
        this.TestBrowser.Source = new Uri(@"path-to-document.doc");
        thread.Abort();  
    }
```

`backgroundCheck` searches for the specific dialogue and invokes the `Open` button

```
    private void backgroundCheck()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        while (true)
        {

            AutomationElement window = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Window));

            if (window!= null)
            {
                AutomationElement downloadWindow = window.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Window));

               if (downloadWindow != null)
                {
                    AutomationElement button = downloadWindow.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "4426"));

                    button.SetFocus();
                     (InvokePattern)button.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern)).Invoke();
                     return;

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Our real application is a bit more complex and uses `MVVM`, `PRISM 5` and `WCF`. We use WCF to load the Word documents from a server. The files are saved in %temp%.

The two `ViewModel`s (edit document / show merged document, each in a `different module`) publish an `event` which the `View`s subscribe to:

```
    public class VmExample
    {
        public delegate void BrowserNavigationEventHandler(string pfad);

        public event BrowserNavigationEventHandler browserNavigate;

        private void navigateToDocument()
        {
             browserNavigate("Path-To-Document.doc"); 
        }
    }

    public partial class ViewMerge : UserControl
    {

        private VmExample _vm;

        public ViewMerge()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContextChanged += ViewMerge_DataContextChanged;
        }

        private void ViewMerge_DataContextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this._vm = e.NewValue as VmExample;

            this._vm.browserNavigate += ViewMerge_browserNavigate;
            this.DataContextChanged -= ViewMerge_DataContextChanged;
        }

        private void ViewMerge_browserNavigate(string path)
        {
            Thread threadCheckDownoadWindow = new Thread(backgroundCheck);
            threadCheckDownoadWindow.Start();
            this.wbBrowser.Source = new Uri(path);
            threadCheckDownoadWindow.Abort();
            this._vm.browserNavigate -= ViewMerge_browserNavigate;
        }

    }
```

We have found the difference in `IsWindowPatternAvailable` with the help of `inspect.exe`. When `IsWindowPatternAvailable = true` the dialogue is a direct child of the `Desktop` and can be found. When `IsWindowPatternAvailable = false` we do not see the dialogue in the `TreeView` of `inspect.exe` but we can access the properties of the dialogue by clicking on it. 
In `inspect.exe` we see the following `ancestors`:

- dialogue itself
- Element ClassName: Shell Embedding
- WebBrowser
- ViewEdit (View to edit the document)
- Application

When we use the code to edit a document in the "merge"-module the dialogue is closed correctly. Both modules reference the same `UIAutomation` DLLs (UIAutomationClient, UIAutomationProvider).

A similar problem is mentioned here:  [AutomationElement shows up using Inspect.exe but does show not up ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282275/automationelement-shows-up-using-inspect-exe-but-does-show-not-up-when-using-uia)
Using a `TreeWalker` or searching the complete `Subtree` of the `AutomationElement.RootElement` do not work.

Any clues why the `IsWindowPatternAvailable` behaves that way are welcome. Other suggestions on how to close the File Download dialogue are also welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution for my problem with the help of this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/abhinaba/2006/07/05/using-uiautomation-events/) using UIAutomationEvents.

```
    AutomationEventHandler UIAEventHandler = new AutomationEventHandler(OnUIAEvent);

    Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(WindowPattern.WindowOpenedEvent,
                    AutomationElement.RootElement,
                    TreeScope.Descendants, UIAEventHandler);
    private static void OnUIAEvent(object src, AutomationEventArgs e)
    {
        AutomationElement element = src as AutomationElement;

        if (element == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        AutomationElement openButton = element.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "4426"));

        if (openButton != null)
        {
            openButton.SetFocus();

            ((InvokePattern)openButton.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern)).Invoke();
        }
    }
```